# How to group endpoints in Nest js with Swagger

Tags: javascript, swagger, nestjs

I want to group API endpoints based on tags in Nest.js such that all employee endpoints under Employee tag, all site endpoints under Site tag etc. Currently, all my endpoints are under default tag. I am using Swagger in Nest.js.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To attach a controller to a specific tag, use the `@ApiTags(...tags)` decorator.

```js
@ApiTags('cats')
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {}
```

[docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/operations#tags)

Comment: This is interesting, it used to work, but now I get `Module '"@nestjs/swagger"' has no exported member 'ApiQuery'`

Comment: @jesse-carter What if we want to put multiple category under one higher category?

For example: panel/articles, panel/posts, panel/users. I think you get the idea.

Comment: @KasirBarati if swagger doesn't support it, I don't think NestJS will do https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1367

Comment: I can confirm it works now, with nestjs project

Answer (score 1):

**To group API endpoints based on tags in Nest.js with Swagger:**

1. **Use Decorators:** Utilize @ApiTags and @ApiOperation decorators to
   specify tags and descriptions for your controllers and endpoints.
2. **Controller Separation:** Create separate controllers for different endpoint groups (e.g., Employee and Site).
3. **Swagger Setup:** Configure Swagger using the @nestjs/swagger package in your application's main file (main.ts or app.module.ts).Ensure you provide tags in the @ApiTags decorator, and Swagger will organize endpoints accordingly in Swagger UI.

**By following these steps, you can neatly organize your API endpoints under specific tags for improved documentation in Swagger UI.**